# Highlight and replace arguments in autocompleted functions in PyDev interpreter

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

When I hit Ctrl-Alt-Enter in PyDev and begin typing a function name into the interpreter, PyDev helpfully offers a list of autocompletions. When I hit Enter, PyDev completes the function name and adds the parameter names, in parentheses. This would be great, except that the parameter names aren't highlighted, so I have to delete the parameters (or type an octothorpe) before I hit enter.

Is there a way either of making PyDev highlight the parameter names (ideally letting you tab to the next one, as it does in the editor) or of omitting them altogether? Having to manually delete the parameters defeats any efficiency gains from autocompletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this cannot be currently configured.

Still, you should be able to apply the completion with Ctrl+Enter (instead of only with Enter). That way the completion is applied without the arguments (nor the parenthesis -- which may not be 100% what you want) -- note that the same can be done in the PyDev editor, not only in the interactive console.

Please add this to the PyDev features tracker.